# PHP check which directory/ php scripts are loaded

Tags: php

Is there anyway for this PHP script to know what are the scripts or directories that are currently loaded? I am talking about my scripts, not specific module

The reason I ask this is because, due to the layers and layers of `include`s ( now don't get me started on what `include` or `include_once` is bad), and due to [autoloading](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/martyr2/index.php?showentry=549), it's kind of difficult to see which PHP scripts can be called because they have been loaded, or which can't be called.

So it would be good if I can just `var_dump` a list of directories or PHP scripts that are already loaded.

Comment: you got to be more specific .. what do you mean by "scripts"? classes? functions? files?

Comment: Are you talking about PHP modules or the files "required" or "included" in that page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [`get_included_files`](http://docs.php.net/get_included_files) to get a list of the included files.

Comment: site note: This list will also include any file that has been "included" by auto_prepend_file